# What are the parametric equations for an object sliding on the curve $y$ = $x^2$?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics

I am writing a JavaScript animation based on real physics. I need the parametric equation for an object sliding on some curves. I would like to start with a parabola, but can't figure out how to derive the equations of motion. The object will be sliding solely under the influence of gravity without friction. How can I derive the equations?

To be clear, this is NOT a projectile, it is an object sliding on a curved surface, the curve which happens to be given by the equation $y$ = $x^2$.

To prevent this question from being closed: what I am looking for are the parametric equations of an object sliding down any curved surface, not just the parabola. I am struggling with deriving these equations because I can't figure out the concept. I would like to know how to do it for a parabola so that I can then generalize the solution for other curves.

Comment: Suppose the parametric equation for x is x = f(t).  In terms of t, what is the parametric equation for y?

Comment: @ChesterMiller Because $y$ = $x^2$, it should be $y$ = $f^2(t)$.

Comment: Did you try to draw a diagram with forces? To start with, just consider a mass on a slope. Then again, any (smooth) curve is locally like a slope.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch I did. By finding the normal force I was able to get $a_x = g \sin \theta \cos\theta$ and $a_y = g(\cos^2 \theta - 1)$. "Zooming" in infinitely, $\theta = \arctan\frac{dy}{dx}$.

Comment: But then you're essentially done -- you have an expression of $a_x\equiv\ddot x$ in terms of $y'(x)$.  (If you want you can use trigonometric identities to get a closed form.)   Then, you have to solve this differential equation, which in most cases will only work numerically

Comment: So ... given you know the solution, can you clarify what you are looking for, then?

Comment: Putting it into [Wolfram-Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%27%27(t)+%3D+9.8+sin(arctan(2x(t)))+*+cos+(arctan(2x(t))))  gives me that, which is not an oscillating solution and cannot be correct.

Comment: Gives you **what**?? For the very least, you have of course lost a minus sign!

Comment: @NorbertSchuch I see my mistake, and am now going to test Farcher's solution.

Comment: The general solution should be $\ddot x = --gy'/(1+(y')^2)$.  Really more of a homework.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch I can get that, the problem is plugging in $2 x(t)$ for $y'$, then attempting to solve for $x(t)$ without the pesky $\ddot x$ in there.

Comment: @theEpsilon Excellent -- then I think you got as far as you can get.  Probably, there is just no closed solution, but if you anyway want to write a computer simulation you can as well numerically integrate the differential equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following on from @NorbertSchuch 's comments.

Assuming no friction there are two forces acting on the mass, its mass $mg$ and the normal reaction to the surface $N$.

[image]

Applying Newton's second law in the $x$ and $y$ directions gives:

$m\ddot y = N \cos \theta - mg$ and $m \ddot x = - N \sin \theta$

$\Rightarrow \dfrac{\ddot x}{\ddot y + g} = - tan \theta = - \dfrac {dy}{dx}$

This is where you put in the equation of your slope which is $y=x^2$ in your case.

$- \dfrac {dy}{dx} = -2 x  \Rightarrow \dfrac{\ddot x}{\ddot y + g} =-2x$

$y=x^2 \Rightarrow \dot y = 2x \dot x \Rightarrow \ddot y = 2 \dot x ^2 + 2 x \ddot x$

This will give you a differential equation for $x(t)$ which I assume has to be solved numerically using Mathematica or some similar package with initial conditions $x(0) = x_o$ and $\dot x(0) = 0$

My free version of WolframAlpha does give a oscillatory solution for $x(t)$ but only as a graph.

[image]

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Thank you for your comment which indicates that it was not clear to me what the original problem was about. So I propose to delete my erroneous answer.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch I agree. A much more difficult problem than the one I thought it was.

Comment: That looks like a messy differential equation.  With the correct derivation, $\ddot x=-gy'(x)/(1+y'(x)^2)$ should be a general solution.

Comment: I think $\frac{dx}{dt}$ should actually be $\frac{dy}{dx}$ in this answer.

Comment: @jdp407 thank you for pointing out the typos which I have now corrected.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Why can this solution only be solved numerically? Does that mean there is no set of parametric equations for the motion?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch  solve[(1+4*x[t]^2)*x''[t]+4*x*(x'[t])^2+20*x[t]=0] produced a general solution (two constants to be fixed by the initial conditions) with WolframAlpha - http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%5B(1%2B4*x%5Bt%5D%5E2)*x%27%27%5Bt%5D%2B4*x*(x%27%5Bt%5D)%5E2%2B20*x%5Bt%5D%3D0%5D  When I put in the initial conditions it ran out of time.  I am surprised that Mathematica did not generate the solution.

Comment: @Farcher Thank you for this answer. I do have access to Mathmatica at my school and will attempt to solve the equation you have given as soon as possible, and if it is correct, mark your solution as such.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch I have not spent much time trying to solve the differential equation other than feeding it into WolframAlpha.  WolframAlpha then gave me an expected oscillatory graph of $x$ against $t$ as shown in my answer if $x(0) =1$ and $\dot x(0) =0$. The initial conditions were set by WolframAlpha.